# String handling and input into search engines (Javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, html

I need help in taking the text in a variable and replacing the "" (spaces) with "`+`",

apending the variable to the end of "`www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=`",

then opening a new tab with that url.

Comment: `-- I am very much a javascript noob sorry.` you can use google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer in response to this comment on Zohaib's answer:

"I think I was using "string" instead of "str" , thats why that bit wasn't working. How would I take it append it to the url and open it in a new tab though?"

```
var search = str.replace(/ /g, '+');
window.open('www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=' + search);
```

`window.open` takes a couple different arguments, check out [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method,

```
var str = 'I am Zohaib';
str.replace(/ /g, '+'); //output: 'I+am+Zohaib'
```

Comment: `str.replace(/ /g, '+')` to replace all instances

Comment: I think I was using "string" instead of "str" , thats why that bit wasn't working. How would I take it append it to the url and open it in a new tab though?

Comment: thanks @Brian, good catch

Comment: @Eidolon I added an answer with the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to `.split(' ').join('_')` your string.